# Best setup to support zero downtime for IF 2010 web farm

Tags: multiple-farms, reliability

I would like to create a SharePoint 2010 production setup, where it is possible to deploy WSP packages to the environment without having to put up a maintainence "page" for the IF web site.

Do any of you have some/any experiences/idears of creating this kind of setup, one way is of course to create a two farm setup. But this will require a content freeze periode as I see it and I would like to avoid (or atleast have a very small content freeze periode (1~2 hours))

Comment: As far as I know this is unavoidable. You shouldn't be deploying WSPs without first informing your users of a short time of unavailability anyway, and doing it out of hours.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! Please **tag by feature or topic** and not by version or product. This helps to attract more attention to your question and keep it relevant. See [How do I use tags](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/) for general guidelines. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only practical way I know for zero downtime is to have the two-farm live/preview setup with DNS switching. You will have to stop content updates between the time you take the content backup and the other farm becoming live.